# How to custom UIViewAnimationCurve like CAMediaTimingFunction's functionWithControlPoints

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation, uiviewanimation

the **UIViewAnimationCurve** only have

- UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
- UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
- UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
- UIViewAnimationCurveLinear

these functions.

but,I need like **ExpoOut** , **BackInOut** animation for UIView.

like ExpoOut is `[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.12 :0.51 :-0.4 :1];`

I has used **CABasicAnimation**,but it can not change **frame** like UIView animation,it very bad when change the view size.

or,are you have any better way to change view frame like real,not look like zoomin.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem here is that it's impossible to specify a timing function for a UIView-based animation. As far as I can tell you're then left with a slew of unpleasant options:

- Switch to using CALayer based animation—with the serious problem that if the delegate is set to a view, the animation doesn't happen. As this is required for UIViews, that's an unappealing option.
- Add parent layer to your views, and animate that layer—with the equally serious problem that this layer will be nowhere in the nib, and modifications to the nib may inadvertently break the animations.
- Don't use a custom timing function.

I hacked my way by setting the delegate to nil right before animating, and setting back to the UIView right after, but it feels very dirty. I may be missing something, though. My code looks something like this:

```
- (void)methodThatAnimates {
    [CATransaction begin]; {
        /* Must set to nil, otherwise the view just jumps to the new location. */
        self.viewToAnimate.layer.delegate = nil;

        CAMediaTimingFunction *timingFunction = 
            [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.4 :0 :0 :1.0];
        [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:timingFunction]
        self.viewToAnimate.layer.position = CGPoint(15.0, 0.0);

        /* Set delegate back to the view, as is required per the 
           Apple documentation. */
        self.viewToAnimate.layer.delegate = self.viewToAnimate;
    } [CATransaction commit];
}
```

So far, it seems to work like a charm, but I keep expecting some bizarre artifact to show up because of the temporarily nil delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [MTAnimation](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTAnimation). It's a UIView Category that provides jQuery like timing functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a limited number of options with media timing functions. You can use the standard ones you list, or provide a couple of control points for a cubic bezier curve. However, the curve you generate can't generate a value less than 0 or greater than 1, since it is used to map linear time to output time.

The control point values you list don't make sense as time values. Unless I'm mistaken, they would cause the timing to go backwards, and go to a value of less than 0.

If you want an arbitrary animation of something like a size, you can use CAKeyFrameAnimation with a series of control points.